# iphone - when exactly does cellForRowAtIndexPath for table views get called and by what in

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I just have a basic (noob) question about cellForRowAtIndexPath get called?

I'm working through example code and I don't see it explicitly called anywhere?

Does any component of type UITableViewComponent automatically call this function when it is created?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When a UITableView is displaying this method gets called per row. In it you will customize each cell with particular data for display.

Here's the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's a sample:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    Item *i = [itemArray objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [i name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [i brewery];
    [i release];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is this method called again as cells scroll in and out of the view?

Comment: Yes it is. You can set a breakpoint or put an NSLog statement in to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is called for each cell when the corresponding UITableView gets drawn. An index path is passed in, and based on the section and cell numbers, your code should generate a UITableViewCell to be displayed in the UI.

You can look [here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/) for a quick tutorial into how UITableViews work.